# Identify characters that have being escaped

Tags: c#, escaping

I am trying to figure out whether a string that contains single or double quotes also contained a backslash character to escape it or not

I noticed that on c#, if I have the following two strings

```
string escaped = "It\'s awesome. \"Yes it is\" ";
string nonEscaped = "It's awesome. Yes it is";
```

then they get printed out in the exact same way (except for the double quotes):

> It's awesome. Yes it is
>
> It's awesome. "Yes it is"

Which makes sense because the escaped characters don't get printed out...

However, I am trying to write a function to identify that It's and "Yes it is" are using escaped characters for the single and double quotes...

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`”` and `\”` are actually **the same**. The backslash is used to escape the quotemark as you can’t just directly write it there because C# compiler will detect it as the end of string. The same goes for apostrophs as we use them to surround individual characters. So if you want to get a single apostroph character you have to escape it: `'\’’`

So to answer your question, there is **no difference** between the `’` and `\’` characters so there’s no way to determine it. You can check it by the next code:

```
string a = "'";
string b = "\'";
Console.WriteLine (a == b); // True
Console.WriteLine (a.Equals(b)); // True
```

Read more about escaping characters in C#: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma#Escaping-whatfor).

Comment: Yes, I got that. I just want to write some logic to check whether or not the backslash was added right before the single quote (let's forget about the double quote for now).

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no way on C# to figure out whether a string had a backslash before a single quote. Right? C# will say that "It's awesome" and "It\'s awesome" are always the same. Correct?

Comment: Correct. You can also write `\u0027` and it will be *the same* `’` character, too. You can read more about escaping characters in the link above.

Answer (score -1):

Try Regex.Unescape(String) Method

Comment: Try posting this as a comment instead of an answer. If you are going to post an answer, it should be more fully fleshed out.